Telegram bot users showing
I created Telegram bot and app using BotFather, and I linked my Vercel link to the app, there is 30+ users used entered my app, but when I search my bot in the Telegram searchbox, I see that my bot have always 4 users only. Here you can see the problem:
enter image description here
I want to edit the 4 users or hide them, can someone please help me.
I tried the hide the users or update them using the BotFather bot not worked.

In fact, no one really knows how the user count for Bots are calculated or considered. I've seen discussions saying that it is the MAU (Monthly Active Users) count.
But, as far as I know many developers have already reported being counts are being in-accurate.

Apart from that, you cannot modify or hide the users count from your end - it's solely up on Telegram. So, don't be stressed - may be Telegram team provides clarification or further info on this later.
Hope this helps.

The bot users are calculated by month, so the number will not update until the users have used it for at least one month. If you want to hide them, delete the bot and telegram will let you create it with the same username instantly. This will reset the monthly user count. Has been working great for me. Hope this helps
